# WPF XAML Style Gallery

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, styles

[WPFThemes](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfthemes) is a good resource for WPF themes and styles. As of now they do not cover many controls like

- Window
- Popup
- Datagrid
- etc..

Is there any other resource to help developer in styling a WPF application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out the [Microsoft Expression Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/site/search/?f[0].Type=RootCategory&f[0].Value=themes&f[0].Text=Themes) to see if that helps you out.  There are several types of window and button styles there.

Comment: These are Silverlight only. No dedicated WPF styles found.